# 'Less fuel is consumed by cars than by fire trucks' : Why 'Composition' and not 'Hasty Generalisation'?

Tags: fallacies

<sub>Source: p 172, *A Concise Introduction to Logic* (12 Ed, 2014) by Patrick Hurley</sub>

Abbreviate the Fallacy of Composition to FC and the Fallacy of Hasty Generalization to FHG.

> To distinguish composition from hasty generalization, therefore, the following procedure
>   should be followed. Examine the conclusion of the argument. If the conclusion
>   is a general statement—that is, a statement in which an attribute is predicated distributively
>   to each and every member of a class—the fallacy committed is hasty generalization.
>   But if the conclusion is a class statement—that is, a statement in which an attribute
>   is predicated collectively to a class as a whole—the fallacy is composition. Example:
>
> [1.] Less fuel is consumed by a car than by a fire truck.
>   [2.] Therefore, less fuel is consumed in the
>   United States by [the class of] cars than by [the class of] fire trucks.
>
> At first sight this argument might appear to proceed from the specific to the general
>   and, consequently, to commit a hasty generalization. But in fact the conclusion is not a general statement at all but a class statement. The conclusion states that the whole class
>   of cars uses less fuel than does the whole class of fire trucks (which is false, because
>   there are many more cars than fire trucks). Since the attribute of using less fuel is predicated
>   collectively, the fallacy committed is composition.

I understand the first paragraph (on the general distinction between FC and HG), but I do not comprehend how 2 is a class statement. To me, 2 can be equally interpreted correctly as 3 below. I accept that 2 is likelier than 3, because 2 asserts a decrease in the mean average of fuel consumption, whereas 3 asserts a decrease in each vehicle's fuel consumption but 3 is certainly possible (For example, if suddenly a law were enacted that allowed only electric cars).

> [3.]  Therefore, less fuel is consumed in the
>   United States by [ALL INDIVIDUAL] cars than by [ALL INDIVIDUAL] fire trucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both statements [2.] and [3.] are statements about the net (aggregate) amount of gas used by the vehicle classes -- therefore they are statements about the collective properties of those classes.

A hasty generalization would be more of the form "therefore for all individual cars the amount of fuel consumes is less than for any individual fire truck".